# Backup your unix server via shell access

Tags: unix, backup, centos

I am looking to backup my dedicated unix server which is running Parallels Plesk Panel v10.4.4_build1013111102.18 os_CentOS 6. The server has Plesk installed but there are some limitations to it's backup settings.

1. I would like to backup to an FTP repository using SFTP
2. Have these backups run weekly every Sunday night at 12AM
3. Backup server settings and content and have it compressed

Are these types of settings something can can be done SSH... or am I limited to what Plesk gives me.

Comment: Great thanks. Yeah I think this could have been created in Serverfault

Comment: I think you can flag it and asked for it to be moved. good luck.

Comment: Do you wait for more suggestions or are you not statisfied with rsnapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://rsnapshot.org/ does it for me.
It does not compress files, but it uses hardlinks for files that have not changed between backup periods, so it is quite space efficient.